# How to support cross-fetch/node-fetch in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, fetch-api, angular-universal

I can't seem to get Angular Universal to wait for `this.pokemonDataService.getList()` in `PokemonListComponent` before the page is served. The `PokemonDataService` uses the `pokeapi-typescript` package which uses the `cross-fetch` and `node-fetch` packages. Using the `fetch` function from `cross-fetch` and `node-fetch` directly doesn't work either, so I think the issue is that Angular is not recognizing that it needs to wait for it.

Using the good old `HttpClient` to directly access the API I need to works fine (e.g `this.pokemonList$ = this.http.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5")`). However, does this mean I need to forgo using the `pokeapi-typescript` altogether and implement what I need myself? Or is there a way to get Angular to "recognize" that it should wait for `cross-fetch`/`node-fetch`? Perhaps creating a wrapper of some sort (wrapping it in straight up `Promise` or `Observable` doesn't seem to work. Wrapping it in `setTimeout` does... but feels so wrong on many levels)?

Thanks for any help.

src/app/pokemon-list/pokemon-list.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { INamedApiResourceList, IPokemon } from 'pokeapi-typescript';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PokemonDataService } from "../pokemon-data.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-list',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-list.component.css']
})
export class PokemonListComponent implements OnInit {

  pokemonList$: Observable<INamedApiResourceList<IPokemon>>

  constructor(private pokemonDataService: PokemonDataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pokemonList$ = this.pokemonDataService.getList()
  }

}
```

---

Files for additional context if needed:

src/app/poke-api.injection-token.ts:

```js
import {InjectionToken} from "@angular/core";
import PokeAPI, { IPokemon } from "pokeapi-typescript";
import { NamedEndpoint } from 'pokeapi-typescript/dist/classes/NamedEndpoint';

export type PokemonEndpoint = NamedEndpoint<IPokemon>;

export const PokeApiToken = new InjectionToken<PokemonEndpoint>('PokeApi', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => PokeAPI.Pokemon,
});
```

src/app/pokemon-data.service.ts:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import {PokeApiToken, PokemonEndpoint} from "./poke-api.injection-token";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonDataService {

  constructor(@Inject(PokeApiToken) private pokeApi: PokemonEndpoint) { }

  getList() {
    return from(this.pokeApi.list(5))
  }

}
```

src/app/pokemon-list/pokemon-list.component.html:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pokemon of (pokemonList$ | async)?.results">
    {{pokemon.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 12/12/20:

In case it helps someone else come up with a better answer (or in the event that there are no others), I'll post what I have working and am moving forward with.

In a nutshell, by creating a macro task through `Zone`, Angular is able to recognize that it should wait for it to complete. Angular's own `HttpClient` among other modules, uses it for the same purpose (and more). `Zone` is a global polyfill provided by Angular's `zone.js` so I think it should be okay to use without fear of something breaking.

To solve the issue, we can create a wrapper and in it create macro tasks to make sure Angular will wait. No updates are needed in the component itself.

/src/util/wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction {
  <T>(
    context: any,
    method: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>,
    ...args: any[]
  ): Observable<T>;
}

export const wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask: WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction = <
  T
>(
  context,
  method,
  ...args
) => {
  return new Observable<T>((subscriber) => {
    const task = Zone.current.scheduleMacroTask(
      'wrapPromiseMethod',
      () => null,
      {},
      () => null,
      () => null
    );

    method
      .bind(context)(...args)
      .then((data) => {
        subscriber.next(data);
        subscriber.complete();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        subscriber.error(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        task.invoke();
      });
  });
};
```

/src/app/wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask.injection-token.ts:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import {
  WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction,
  wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask,
} from '../util/wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask';

export const WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskToken = new InjectionToken<WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction>(
  'WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask',
  {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask,
  }
);
```

/src/app/pokemon-data.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { INamedApiResourceList, IPokemon } from 'pokeapi-typescript';
import { WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction } from 'src/util/wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask';
import { PokeApiToken, PokemonEndpoint } from './poke-api.injection-token';
import { WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskToken } from './wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask.injection-token';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PokemonDataService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskToken)
    private wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask: WrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTaskFunction,
    @Inject(PokeApiToken) private pokeApi: PokemonEndpoint
  ) {}

  getList() {
    return this.wrapPromiseMethodAsMacroTask<INamedApiResourceList<IPokemon>>(
      this.pokeApi,
      this.pokeApi.list,
      5
    );
  }
}
```

Also make sure to include `"zone.js"` in `compilerOptions.types` of the `tsconfig.js`, `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.server.json` to let TypeScript recognize `Zone` as a global and type it.

FYI, `zone.js` types were giving me a lot of trouble and after some research I figured out I had to update to Angular 11 as well as `zone.js` version 0.11.3 (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37531). If you don't you may have NodeJS typing conflicts and might need to resort to either copying the typings needed and create your own `*.d.ts` or use `any`.

Source which gave a clue to this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15278#issuecomment-326034463

I'll wait a week or so for a better answer, otherwise will just accept this one.

Comment: FYI it's probably easier to wrap this code into an Angular Service rather than a separate function and then use it via injection token as I did.